# BeautifulSoup - Scraping a comment when the ID field changes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, comments

I'm scraping baseball game data for a number of seasons.  Here's an example of the data.

https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml

For this question, I'm specifically looking for a way to pull out the comments that contain the umpire and game data.  Note, these html files are now stored locally, so I'm trying to iterate through a folder.  In the source code it looks like this:

```
           <div class="section_wrapper setup_commented commented" id="all_342042674">
<div class="section_heading">
  <span class="section_anchor" id="342042674_link" data-label="Other Info"></span>
    <h2>Other Info</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>      
</div><div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--  
    <div class="section_content" id="div_342042674">
<div><strong>Umpires:</strong> HP - Greg Gibson, 1B - Jerry Layne, 2B - Jordan Baker, 3B - Vic Carapazza.</div><div><strong>Time of Game:</strong> 3:21.</div>
<div><strong>Attendance:</strong> 33,809.</div>
<div><strong>Start Time Weather:</strong> 70&deg; F, Wind 6mph out to Centerfield, Night, No Precipitation.</div>

    </div>

-->  
</div>
```

As you can see it's inside a comment.  The real challenge is that the ID value changes between venues and seasons.  I'm parsing through 10 years of data.  Can someone tell me how to pull the comment text when the ID actually changes?
Here's my code:

```
# import libraries and files
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import os

print

# Setup Games list for append
games = []

path = r"D:\My Web Sites\baseball 2\www.baseball-reference.com\boxes\ANA"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".html"):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

        print 'Processing {:}...'.format(fullpath)

# Get Page, Make Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath), 'lxml')

# Setting up game object to append to list
    game = {}

# Get Description
    # Note:  Skip every other child because of 'Navigable Strings' from BS.  
    divs = soup.findAll('div', {'scorebox_meta'})
    for div in divs:
        for idx, child in enumerate(div.children):
            if idx == 1:
                game['date'] = child.text
            elif idx == 3:
                game['start_time'] = child.text.split(':', 1)[1].strip()
            elif idx == 7:
                game['venue'] = child.text.split(':', 1)[1].strip()
            elif idx == 9:
                game['duration'] = child.text.split(':', 1)[1].strip()


# Get Player Data from tables
    for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)):
         data = BeautifulSoup(comment,"lxml")
         for items in data.select("table tr"):
             player_data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("th,td")]
             print(player_data)
             print '======================================================='

# Get Umpire Data        



# Append game data to full list        
    games.append(game)

    print

print 'Results'
print '*' * 80

# Print the games harvested to the console

for idx, game in enumerate(games):
    print str(idx) + ':  ' + str(game)

# Write to CSV
csvfile = "C:/Users/Benny/Desktop/anatest.csv"

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(game)
```

Thanks so much,
Benny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `re` module to extract the comment section:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = """<div class="section_wrapper setup_commented commented" id="all_342042674">
<div class="section_heading">
  <span class="section_anchor" id="342042674_link" data-label="Other Info"></span>
    <h2>Other Info</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div><div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--
    <div class="section_content" id="div_342042674">
<div><strong>Umpires:</strong> HP - Greg Gibson, 1B - Jerry Layne, 2B - Jordan Baker, 3B - Vic Carapazza.</div>
<div><strong>Time of Game:</strong> 3:21.</div>
<div><strong>Attendance:</strong> 33,809.</div>
<div><strong>Start Time Weather:</strong> 70&deg; F, Wind 6mph out to Centerfield, Night, No Precipitation.</div>

    </div>

-->
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(re.search(r'(?<=<!--)(.*?)(?=-->)', data, flags=re.DOTALL)[0], 'lxml')

umpires, time_of_game, attendance, start_time_weather = soup.select('div.section_content > div')

print('ID: ', soup.find('div', class_="section_content")['id'])
print('umpires: ', umpires.text)
print('time of game: ', time_of_game.text)
print('attendance: ', attendance.text)
print('start_time_weather: ', start_time_weather.text)
```

Output:

```
ID:  div_342042674
umpires:  Umpires: HP - Greg Gibson, 1B - Jerry Layne, 2B - Jordan Baker, 3B - Vic Carapazza.
time of game:  Time of Game: 3:21.
attendance:  Attendance: 33,809.
start_time_weather:  Start Time Weather: 70° F, Wind 6mph out to Centerfield, Night, No Precipitation.
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej,  I'll have to learn more about the re module. Seems that might be difficult to pull the data item since i have 20k+ files to iterate through.

Comment: Andrej, I'm getting a NoneType object error.  I changed the data section to the below.  Thoughts?

`path = r"D:\My Web Sites\baseball 2\www.baseball-reference.com\boxes\ANA\ANA201806180.html"

# Get Column_Headers

soup = BeautifulSoup(re.search(r'(?<=<!--)(.*?)(?=-->)', path, flags=re.DOTALL)[0], 'lxml')`

Comment: @Benny That means that there isn't any comment section (`<!-- ... -->`) in the data. Firstly check if `re.search(r'(?<=<!--)(.*?)(?=-->)', data, flags=re.DOTALL)` isn't `None`, and then access it by index `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you kick out those vicious signs `<!--`,`-->` from the html elements, you can easily access the content. This is how you can go:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml"

res = requests.get(url)
content = res.text.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
umpire, gametime, attendance, weather = soup.find_all(class_="section_content")[2]("strong")
print(f'{umpire.next_sibling}\n{gametime.next_sibling}\n{attendance.next_sibling}\n{weather.next_sibling}\n')
```

Output:

```
 HP - Greg Gibson, 1B - Jerry Layne, 2B - Jordan Baker, 3B - Vic Carapazza.
 3:21.
 33,809.
 70° F, Wind 6mph out to Centerfield, Night, No Precipitation.
```

Comment: Ah!  I hadn't thought of pulling out the comments.  Once I do that, I'll need to adjust my table data pull, but it looks like it'll be nice and clean.  Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.  @SIM I'm getting a syntax error on the print line for the umpire pull.

Comment: You are right. Although the content of that page are static, the ID name changes dynamically.

Comment: hey @SIM i think i had a syntax error because i'm using 2.7 and I think print function is 3.0+?

Comment: is there a way to use requests.get for the content not for URL?  I'm trying to make the script loop through all the game files in my folder.

`path = r"D:\My Web Sites\baseball 2\www.baseball-reference.com\boxes\ANA"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".html"):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)`

Comment: Looks like i've been able to get the requests item resolved by pointing it at "path" which i define as a local folder.  however, now i have a out of index error.  When I counted the number of "section_content' tags after comments are removed, it looked like there were 7 and this was the last one.  I tried changing the range to 6 and 7 but no luck.
  `File "C:/Users/Benny/Desktop/Baseball_scrape.py", line 42, in <module>
    umpires = soup.find_all(class_="section_content")[2]("strong")

IndexError: list index out of range`